# Installed Oracle Java but when installing software I get `Your version of Java is not supported.`

Tags: debian, java

I am trying to install the following [software](https://www.link-assistant.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/165/3/how-to-install-seo-powersuite-on-ubuntu) on my `debian jessie` machine

```
root@www:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for root:
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1082      auto mo                                       de
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual                                        mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1082      manual                                        mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1081      manual                                        mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

When I want to install the software I get:

```
> sudo ./install.sh
Your version of Java is not supported.
Please update your Java to version 1.8 or newer to be able to use the software on your computer.
```

Any suggestions why I do not find the proper java version?

Comment: Choice number `3` looks promising, as `1.8` likely corresponds to `java 8` (blame the Sun marketing department for that version number bump?)

Comment: Anti-oracle conspiracy, obviously.

Comment: Delete your outdated and probably unsupported Java 7.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The software you're installing is looking for Java 1.8, also known as Java 8. You need to pick choice 3 in the alternatives configuration.